# Можно ли сделать рассылку из админки(DJANGO) в телеграм бот(на python)?

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно сделать рассылку для тех кто оформил подписку на бот, через админ панель django или другие.Бот на пайтон.Как сделать вывод текста из админ панели в телеграм бот по id чата или какую лучше админку использовать использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, мой способ решения этой проблемы еще актуален
Допустим у нас есть функция `get_mailing_user_id()`, которая возвращает id тех пользователей, которым нужно сделать рассылку.
Я реализовал рассылку через `actions` (в `admin.py`).

```
    def publish(self, request, queryset):
    """Опубликовать"""
    row_update = queryset.update(draft=True)
    bot_mailing(ids=get_mailing_user_id(queryset.filter(draft=True)[0].id),
                m_message=queryset.filter(draft=True)[0].text, image=queryset.filter(draft=True)[0].media)
    if row_update == 1:
        message_bit = "1 рассылка была опубликована"
    else:
        message_bit = f"{row_update} рассылок были опубликованы"
    self.message_user(request, f"{message_bit}")

publish.short_description = "Разослать"
publish.allowed_permissions = ('change',)
```

здесь `bot_mailing` это функция, которая принимает в себя различного рода аргументы (id пользователей, текст и фотографию)

Реализация `bot_mailing`:

```
def bot_mailing(ids, m_message, image):
bot = Bot(token = constants.TOKEN)
for i in ids:

    try:
        if image != '':
            bot.sendPhoto(i, photo=open('Path' + image.name, 'rb'),
                          caption=m_message)
        else:
            bot.sendMessage(i, m_message)
    except:
        pass
```

При этом у меня есть обычный хэндлер, обычные функции(start и тд)
То есть код выглядит так:

```
from django.utils import timezone
import pytz
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, Update, Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
import logging

from . import constants
import ugc.models

from ...models import Users

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)


def start(update, context):
    ...


def answer_questions(update, context: CallbackContext):
    ...


def bot_mailing(ids, m_message, image):
    bot = Bot(token = constants.TOKEN)
    for i in ids:

        try:
            if image != '':
                bot.sendPhoto(i, photo=open('Path' + image.name, 'rb'),
                              caption=m_message)
            else:
                bot.sendMessage(i, m_message)
        except:
            pass


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Телеграм бот'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        updater = Updater(token=constants.TOKEN, use_context=True)
        dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

        job_queue = updater.job_queue

        start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
        answer_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.all, answer_questions)
        dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
        dispatcher.add_handler(answer_handler)
        updater.start_polling(timeout=5, clean=True)
```